# Headless Browser working on app engine ?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is there any good solution or some Headless Browser I can use on GAE ? I working on an application, on GAE, where the application is going to read some web pages, parse them, and do some statistics on them. There is discussion going [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/feature-requests/162/), to make HTMLUnit working on GAE but I am not sure if it is going to work anyway.

Comment: If you're okay with just getting the HTML (and not executing Javascript), http://jsoup.org/ might be worth a look.

Comment: I will take a look. In fact I am not concerned with JS :)

Comment: At least not at this stage.

Comment: Would you answer the question so I can vote ?

Comment: There you go, it's not much but if it helps you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with just getting the HTML (and not executing Javascript), [jsoup.org](http://jsoup.org/) might be worth a look:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```

(sample code shamelessly copied from jsoup)